# Adding buttons above mapfragment

Tags: android

I am a beginner to maps programming in android. I am trying to add a row of buttons above my mapfragment as per the layout below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tilt"
        android:onClick="tilt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Move" 
        android:onClick="move"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/mymap">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    GoogleMap gm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.finallay);
        MapFragment mp=new MapFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.mymap,mp).commit();
    }
}
```

However ,the resulting view does not show the map rather only the buttons.am i making some mistake here.
Without adding buttons the fragment tag is working fine.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your button bar `LinearLayout` height is `match_parent` so there's no more room for the map container layout. Change the button bar height to `wrap_content`.

Also while there, you should change the map container `LinearLayout` height to `0px` and set a non-zero `layout_weight` on it so it will automatically get all remaining space in the parent `LinearLayout`.